# Laptop without screen

Tags: system-installation, laptop, live-cd, initramfs

I'm trying to give my old laptop a new life. The screen broke, so i removed it and i am planning to turn it into a media center. It's a HP Pavilion M6 laptop.

It perfectly starts from a live CD, but when I install Ubuntu/Lubuntu/Xubuntu i get a black screen and after a few minutes a screen full with weird characters. i tried adding `radeon.modeset=0` and `video=LVDS-1:d` to my GRUB command line but this didn't change anything at all.

When I go in recovery mode, I get error `gave up waiting for root device`. Then I found online that it should be possible to reach the hard drive, but in `/dev` the entire `sda` is missing while working from the `(initramfs)` prompt, while on the live CD I see it.

How can I fix this problem? `sudo parted -l` shows this:

[image: partitions]

update 1: 
now i get this error : ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xx$ does not exist when i  change in the grub setings it should use /dev/sda1 instead it gives the same error. from the live cd i can still see this harddrive

update 2:
The entire /dev/disk doesnt seem to be there in the initramfs console. it also seems to be stuck on "Switched to clocksource tsc"  for a long time. I also tried formatting to ext3 and setting a rootdelay=90 but both didnt help

Comment: Do you get the "weird characters" screen during installation or after installation? Could you share the output of `sudo parted -l` from a live CD?

Comment: it doesnt show any signs of problems while installing.. it happens after the reboot of the installation. this is what sudo parted-l outputed: http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-3268-276.html

Comment: Have you tried adding the `nomodeset` kernel option at boot (in GRUB)? I'm not sure if it'll help, but it's worth a try

Comment: I tried to do this.. it gets me partly to the answer.. now i get the same error as i did in recovery mode.